# Asignar resultados de un WHILE a una Variable

Tags: php, mysql, while, php7

chicos tengo el siguiente caso:
Poseo el siguiente codigo:

```
 $sql ="SELECT * FROM monto LIMIT $limite_base, $l ";
$resultadosql = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($rowsql=mysqli_fetch_row($resultadosql)){
  printf ("%s\nBsS\n", $rowsql[1]);
  $montos_permitidos = $rowsql[1];
}
```

Prácticamente lo que quiero es que la variable $montos_permitidos sea igual a la salida que me da printf pero no he logrado como hacerlo.
Si lo dejo como esta la variable $montos_permitidos me como salida el ultimo dato de mi Base de datos.
Los valores de mi tabla son algo como esto:

```
id  monto
1   20
2   30
3   40
4   50
5   60
```

Para mi fuera ideal que la salida fuera algo similar a:

```
20 BsS, 30 BsS y 40 BsS
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es que la variable te vaya acumulando los datos tienes que ir concatenando la respuesta que quieres.

La forma más fácil de entender eso es este ejemplo:

```
     $sql ="SELECT * FROM monto LIMIT $limite_base, $l ";
$resultadosql = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$num_datos = mysqli_num_rows($resultadosql);
while ($rowsql=mysqli_fetch_row($resultadosql)){
    if($num_datos ==1)
    {
       $montos_permitidos = $montos_permitidos . "y " . $rowsql[1] . " BsS";
    }
    else
    {
       //printf ("%s\nBsS\n", $rowsql[1]);
       $montos_permitidos = $montos_permitidos . $rowsql[1] . " BsS, ";
    }
    $num_datos--;
}
```

Comment: De verdad nunca pensé que de esa manera era que se hacia, sobre todo en la parte de `$montos_permitidos = $montos_permitidos .` y si quisiera que ente el penultimo y ultimo dato recuperado se escriba la letra `y` con la finalidad de dar un resultado como este: `20 BsS, 30 BsS y 40 BsS` lógicamente como usted gentilmente me ha orientado me funciona pero si logro colocarlo como la salida propuesta seria mucho mejor.. igual aceptare su respuesta que me fue de solución a mi interrogante..!

Comment: Sería obtener el numero de datos e ir restandolo hasta que sea el último y cambias la forma de añadir el dato.